# List name of employees who work in that location and name of their companies

Tags: sql

3 tables

```sql
PEOPLE { id, name,  company_id }
COMPANIES { id, name, location_id }
LOCATION {id, name}
```

My query:

```sql
SELECT PEOPLE.NAME, COMPANIES.NAME 
FROM PEOPLE, COMPANIES, LOCATIONS
WHERE PEOPLE.COMPANY_ID = COMPANIES.ID 
  AND LOCATIONS.ID = COMPANIES.LOCATION_ID 
  AND LOCATIONS.ID
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  This has been part of the SQL language for multiple *decades*.

Comment: *"What i am doing wrong?"* `AND LOCATIONS.ID` what?

Comment: Can anyone guide?

Comment: Also, don't tag spam. SQL Server and SQLite are completely different RBDMS and MySQLi is a PHP extension to interacting with MySQL (Another RDBMS).

Comment: alright won't do it.

Comment: You've 2 comments offering advice so far, @HELLO : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68071836/list-name-of-employees-who-work-in-that-location-and-name-of-their-companies#comment120313951_68071836), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68071836/list-name-of-employees-who-work-in-that-location-and-name-of-their-companies#comment120314008_68071836)

Comment: Remove the (now) last line but add a proper ORDER BY clause. Try that and, if that does not meet your needs then reply back with the results, a clear description of your needs and why the query does not satisfy them.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.NAME AS Person, 
    c.NAME AS Company
FROM 
    PEOPLE p
INNER JOIN
    COMPANIES c ON p.company_id = c.id
INNER JOIN
    LOCATIONS l ON c.location_id = l.id
WHERE 
    l.Name = '(your desired location here)'
```

- Proper ANSI JOINs
- Define the location you want in the `WHERE` clause
- That's it already!

Answer (score 0):

Please use proper join syntax for better understanding.

```
SELECT PEOPLE.NAME, COMPANIES.NAME 
FROM PEOPLE 
inner join COMPANIES 
      on PEOPLE.COMPANY_ID = COMPANIES.ID 
inner join LOCATIONS
      on LOCATIONS.ID = COMPANIES.LOCATION_ID 
where l.Name ='LocationName'
```

Answer (score 0):

**By location name**

```sql
SELECT _p.Id,_p.[Name],_c.name
FROM PEOPLE _p
JOIN Company _c ON _p.company_id = _c.Id
JOIN Location _l ON _c.location_id = _l.Id
WHERE _l.[Name] = 'your location Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use proper `JOIN`.

```
SELECT p.NAME AS Employee, c.name AS Company
FROM PEOPLE p 
INNER JOIN COMPANY c ON p.company_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN LOCATION lo ON c.location_id = lo.id
WHERE lo.name = 'Desired location';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name AS people_name, c.name AS companies_name
FROM People p
INNER JOIN Companies c ON p.company_id = c.id
INNER JOIN Locations l ON c.location_id = l.id
WHERE l.name = (
  SELECT name
  FROM Locations
  GROUP BY name
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
);
```